Reading a PNG in c++
I am trying to make a script that takes a PNG file, reads it and converts the data to hexadecimal, and adds it to a new file. I wrote the script and everything works as normal, except the information being read and sent to the new file is partially incorrect.
This is my script:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream newImage("gradient-test.txt");
    std::fstream Image("rainbow-gradient-test.png");
    Image.seekg(0, std::iostream::end);
    int size = Image.tellg();

    for (int target = 0; target <= size; target += 1)
    {
        Image.seekg(target, std::iostream::beg);
        int color = Image.peek();
        newImage << std::hex << color;
        newImage << " ";
    }
    newImage.close();
    return 0;
}

This is rainbow-gradient-test.png:
rainbow-gradient-test.png
This is the contents of gradient-test.txt:
89 50 4e 47 a a ffffffff a 0 0 0 d 49 48 44 52 0 0 0 80 0 0 0 44 8 2 0 0 0 c6 25 aa 3e 0 0 0 c2 49 44 41 54 78 5e ed d4 81 6 c3 30 14 40 d1 b7 34 dd ff ff 6f b3 74 56 ea 89 12 6c 28 73 e2 aa 34 49 3 87 d6 fe d8 7b 89 bb 52 8d 3b 87 fe 1 0 80 0 0 10 0 0 2 0 40 0 0 8 0 0 1 0 20 0 0 4 0 80 0 0 10 0 0 2 0 40 0 0 8 0 0 1 0 20 0 0 0 d4 5e 6a 64 4b 94 f5 98 7c d1 f4 92 5c 5c 3e cf 9c 3f 73 71 58 5f af 8b 79 5b ee 96 b6 47 eb f1 ea d1 ce b6 e3 75 3b e6 b9 95 8d c7 ce 3 39 c9 af c6 33 93 7b 66 37 cf ab bf f9 c9 2f 8 80 0 0 10 0 0 2 0 40 0 0 8 0 0 1 0 20 0 0 4 0 80 0 0 10 0 0 2 0 40 0 0 8 0 0 1 0 20 0 0 8c 37 db 68 3 20 fb ed 96 65 0 0 0 0 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82 ffffffff 

I would prefer not to use any extra libraries.
I have tried using different methods of reading the PNG files that I could understand, but none have worked. I am relatively new to programming in c++ so bare with me please. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

int color = Image.peek() & 0xFF;  And possibly you'll also want to open the PNG file as a binary.

PNG files have the image data compressed so you won't be reading the image data / extracting the pixel data using this method. I am unsure what you expect to do with the hex you generate.

What's wrong with using a PNG library?

Download the PNG Specification.  Read the file header in as a binary file.  See if it is compressed or not.  Decompress the file into another array if necessary.  You can't read the first couple of bytes as the pixels.  You'll need to know how many channels, the supported bits per channel.    So much easier to use a library.

if your goal is actually using the pixel data you need to use a library. Remember experienced programmers spent many thousands of hours developing the libraries that read PNG. There is no way a beginner is going to implement their own library in a few short hours even one that covers a small subset of the functionality.

I see a lot of things wrong with this small code:

you can use std::filesystem::file_size() or equivalent, instead of using Image.seekg()+Image.tellg(). Also, your loop has an off-by-1 error that goes out of bounds of the file's size.  However, in this situation, you don't actually need the file size at all as you can use Image.get() instead of Image.seekg()+Image.peek();

you should use std::ifstream instead of std::fstream. Either way, open the PNG file in binary mode to avoid any data conversions, such as line break translations.

peek() returns an signed int. If a byte has its high bit set to 1, you risk sign-extending the return value.  You would have to mask off the unwanted bits.  Also, peek() returns Traits::eof() on failure, which in this case is the EOF constant, which has a negative integer value that you are not handling.

you are not including <iomanip> for the I/O manipulators you are using.


Try this instead:
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream newImage("gradient-test.txt");
    std::ifstream Image("rainbow-gradient-test.png", std::ios::binary);
    char ch;

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    while (Image.get(ch)) {
        newImage << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned>(ch) << ' ';
    }

    newImage.close();
    return 0;
}


This is a useful answer. I just added a different one explaining why the original code didn't work (apart from being terribly inefficient).

Since EOF is often -1, doesn't that suggest that peak() returns a value between 0 and +255 for the byte read? Otherwise you could not read -1 from a file (if that is EOF's value), as it would sign-extend to the EOF value.

I agree: the masking adds clarity but it's not really necessary. For a char (single byte) based stream, all valid values are positive int numbers between 0 and 255 (sign extension doesn't hurt, and the masking makes no difference) and EOF is negative (usually -1).

I agree with most of the comments: your code is terribly inefficient.
Said that, the problem (as @Eljay suggested) was in the open mode. It must be binary. If you debug the code and/or check the PNG file contents, you'll see there's a 0x00 byte at position (target) == 8. When the file is opened in text mode (the default), the Image.peek() function interprets this 0x00 as an (alternative) end-of-file marker, and it returns a -1 (which you can actually see in your original output file as the first "ffffffff") (a second "ffffffff", which is at the end, signals the actual end-of-file, because you're also trying to read one extra byte past the end of the file).
This code corrects this problem:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream newImage("gradient-test.txt");
    std::fstream Image("rainbow-gradient-test.png", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    Image.seekg(0, std::iostream::end);
    int size = Image.tellg();

    for (int target = 0; target < size; target += 1)  // Beware: stop before target == size
    {
        Image.seekg(target, std::iostream::beg);
        int color = Image.peek();
        if (color == -1) {
            std::cout << " eof()=" << Image.eof();
            std::cout << " fail()=" << Image.fail();
            std::cout << " bad()=" << Image.bad();
            std::cout << "\n";
            return 1;
        }
        color = color & 0xFF;
        newImage << std::hex << color;
        newImage << " ";
    }
    newImage.close();
    return 0;
}

